# Speech recognition is too slow using sapi sdk 11 in Visual Studio

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I have tried VB in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 with framework 4.5 I check "Microsoft Speech Object Library ver 11" in my references after installing the Speech SDK versionn 11. I then import "SpeechLib" and instantiate speech with:

```
Public WithEvents m_Recocontext As SpInProcRecoContext 
Public m_Recognizer As SpInprocRecognizer              
Public m_Grammar As ISpeechRecoGrammar
```

and in Form_Load:

```
m_Recocontext = New SpInProcRecoContext
m_Recognizer = CType(m_Recocontext.Recognizer, SpInprocRecognizer) 
m_Grammar = m_Recocontext.CreateGrammar(0)
Dim grammarfile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\grammartest.xml"
m_Grammar.CmdLoadFromFile(grammarfile, SpeechLoadOption.SLODynamic)
m_Recocontext.EventInterests = SpeechRecoEvents.SREAllEvents
m_Recocontext.RetainedAudio = CType((m_Recocontext.RetainedAudio = SpeechRetainedAudioOptions.SRAORetainAudio), SpeechRetainedAudioOptions)
```

Then in my "SpeechOn" routine I connect the audio path to my telephony device on a phone call like this:

```
m_AudioIn = New SpMMAudioIn
m_AudioIn.DeviceId = TelePhoneLine.WaveRecordID
m_AudioIn.Format.Type = SpeechAudioFormatType.SAFT8kHz16BitMono                
m_Recognizer.AudioInputStream = m_AudioIn                              
m_Grammar.CmdSetRuleIdState(1, SpeechRuleState.SGDSActive)
```

Here is my grammar file:

```
<GRAMMAR LANGID="409">
<RULE ID="1" Name="number" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
<L PROPNAME="number">
<P VAL="1">+one</P>
<P VAL="2">+two</P>
<P VAL="3">+three</P>
<P VAL="4">+four</P>
<P VAL="5">+five</P>
<P VAL="6">+six</P>
<P VAL="7">+seven</P>
<P VAL="8">+eight</P>
<P VAL="9">+nine</P>
<P VAL="0">+zero</P>
</L>
</RULE>
<RULE ID="2" Name="yesno" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
<L PROPNAME="yesno">
<P VAL="1">+yes</P>
<P VAL="2">+no</P>
<P VAL="3">+maybe</P>
</L>
</RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

My "OnRecognition" event fires every time I speak a command and control word from my .XML Grammar file which is very small, usually just 0-9 or even just 1 or 2 (press 1 for yes and 2 for no). If I speak "1...2...3...4...5" at a normal pace, it misses every other number or every third number. If I speak 1 number per second, it gets them all. What trick am I missing to make speech recognition fast enough to be usable?

And here is the final working version. "propname" had to be added in the  tag or it would not load.

```
<GRAMMAR LANGID="409">
    <RULE ID="1" Name="number" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
    <PHRASE min="5" max="7">
        <RULEREF Name="digits" propname="digits"/>
    </PHRASE>
    </RULE>
    <RULE Name="digits">
        <L PROPNAME="digits">
            <P VAL="0">0</P>
            <P VAL="1">1</P>
            <P VAL="2">2</P>
            <P VAL="3">3</P>
            <P VAL="4">4</P>
            <P VAL="5">5</P>
            <P VAL="6">6</P>
            <P VAL="7">7</P>
            <P VAL="8">8</P>
            <P VAL="9">9</P>
        </L>
    </RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

Comment: It’s likely your grammar, which you haven’t shared.  Grammars match utterances, which are separated by silence.  If you want to recognize digit sequences, your grammar must specify digit sequences, not just digits.

Comment: I added my grammar file. I need to get account numbers, so the numbers could be millions of combinations ("123456", "8937493", etc.). Do I need to use dictation mode instead of command and control mode for that portion of the code and go back to dictation for one word answers to questions like "is this correct, yes or no?" or "press or say 1 for jim, 2 for mary, 3 for steve"? And if the answer is yes, I probably should post a separate question because dictationload() will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change your grammars (using the [SAPI Grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634(v=vs.85).aspx) spec) to specify an account number.   Assuming your account numbers are 7-10 digits long, you could use something like this:

```
<rule name="accountno">
  <phrase min="7" max="10">
    <ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
  </phrase>
</rule>

<rule name="digit">
  <l>
    <p val="0">0</p>
    <p val="1">1</p>
    <p val="2">2</p>
    <p val="3">3</p>
    <p val="4">4</p>
    <p val="5">5</p>
    <p val="6">6</p>
    <p val="7">7</p>
    <p val="8">8</p>
    <p val="9">9</p>
  </l>
</rule>
```

Comment: Great! I had to tweak things a bit and despite using Notepad++ and checking for any strange characters, it wouldn't work. Typing it all in manually made it work. Most importantly, it would not load the file without "propname="digits" after the L tag as shown in my version in my edit to the original question